# Android sticky CollapsingToolbarLayout in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to add a behaviour to my CollapsingToolbarLayout such that the "collapsible" content is sticky (image) in this case. Only the bottom sheet needs to be scrollable and it will overlay the images in the ViewPager. Attaching recording video for better understanding.

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/trmpy__f9Is

The expected behaviour is as shown the image below where the header should stick and footer should overlay it when scrolled.
[image: Expected behaviour]

Code is something like this-

```
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2/>

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar />

                    <ConstraintLayoutForSomeContent/>

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also tried playing with `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` and `app:layout_scrollFlags="noScroll"` to `CollapsibleToolbarLayout`, `AppBarLayout` with no luck.

The other option was not making ViewPager part of the `CollapsibleToolbarLayout` which solves the purpose but then the ViewPager is not scrollable anymore as the touch is consumed by the overlaying CollapsibleToolbarLayout.

Is there a way this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

add the below line in your view pager

```
app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0"
```

change the value you want between 1 to 0.9

Comment: Thank you so much brother. This worked like a charm. For some reason I had to put value 1.00001 as 1.0 wasn't really working. But this also helped me understand that even though the documentation says the value needs to be between 0 and 1, if you provide value>1 the parallax works in reverse direction i.e. goes down instead of up when scrolled up :D